# Отправка объекта собственного класса по UDP

Tags: c#, udp

Как отправить объект пользовательского класса по UDP? Допустим у нас уже установлено соединение и нам нужно только получить байты объекта, чтобы отправить их по UDP. Так вопрос такой: как получить байты объекта класса?
Допустим, есть такой класс:

```
public class Value
{
    protected Value(string name, double divider = 1.0)
    {
        Name = name;
        Divider = divider;
    }

    protected readonly string[] ValuesDependentOnG = {"axis_x", "axis_y",
            "axis_z", "gir_x", "gir_y", "gir_z"};

    protected const int SizeOfIntValue = sizeof(int);
    protected const int SizeOfPhysValue = sizeof(double);

    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly double Divider;
    public int IntValue { get; protected set; }
    public double PhysValue { get; protected set; }
}
```

Как получить байты объект данного класса и отправить по UDP?

Comment: Ваша задача разбивается на две части: преобразование объекта в массив байт и передача массива байт по UDP.

Comment: Это - разные задачи, и решать их надо отдельно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov моя задача уже реализовано таким способом. Просто слышал про сериализацию и думал может есть уже готовые варианты какие-нибудь

Comment: Конечно же есть готовые варианты. Для каждой из задач отдельно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я имел в виду универсальный метод сериализации объекта пользовательского класса

Comment: Да, такие методы есть. Может быть, вы их даже найдете если начнете искать про сериализацию, а не про UDP.